# Laravel post owner relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

i have `category_content`, `contents` and `users` tables which each `contents` belong to many `category_content` and `category_content`belong to many `contents` and each `contents` belongs to one user and one user has many post on `contents` table

```
class Contents extends Model
{
    ...

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ContentCategories::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    ...

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contents::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contents::class);
    }
}
```

by this below code i can find categories content that category id is `7`

```
$nodejsContents = ContentCategories::find('7')->contents;
```

now, problem is here, how can i get post owner in this query which content is belongs to which user

i tested this code but i get error:

```
$nodejsContents = ContentCategories::find('7')->contents->user;
```

Error:

```
"Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$contents"
```

`contents_categories` migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contents_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('lang',2)->default('fa');
        $table->integer('parent')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: could you add the table/migration/schema structure of the `ContentCategories` model?

Comment: What is `user` here `find('7')->contents->user;`

Comment: @C2486 its only for test and i get error

Comment: @Quezler post updated

Comment: But what is type of value for `user`

Comment: can you do a `dd(ContentCategories::find('7'))` to confirm that its not `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ContentCategories::find('7')->contents
```

`belongsToMany` Contents would return a collection. So you could either loop through the collection to get the related user of `Contents`

or

```
ContentCategories::find(7)->contents->with('user');
```

Comment: `ContentCategories::find(7)->contents->with('user');` is correct

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why?

Comment: i up-voted your post not down-voted that, i don't know who down-voted your post :(

Answer (score 2):

`user` is within `contents`, so access with closure,

```
$nodejsContents = ContentCategories::has('contents')->with(['contents' => function($query){
                                        $query->with('user')->get();
                                    }])->find('7');
```

Comment: `contents` collection is empty here

Comment: thanks this post as https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443631/1830228 resolve my problem